# Blogger Hidden OG:Image for Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, wordpress-theming, facebook-opengraph, blogger

I would like to ask two things:

1. How is it that some blogs or websites have hidden og:image? Let me explain, there are blogs that when I share their post's links to Facebook, there is a large Thumbnail. But the post HAS NO image at all, sometimes there are photos but then when you post the link, the og:image/thumbnail is not even there in the post.
2. I have a site/blog also, when you copy a link of any of my posts to Facebook debugger or Facebook itself, the thumbnails are large, which is my goal. But then when you share my posts' link using the SHARE BUTTON, the preview (there will be new tab or new pop up, and before you click the SHARE button) is large but if you look at your WALL, the thumbnail is small :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as answered in my question on google forum (by KobusNL), the og:image part should be like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

^I'm so happy that one of my questions is solved!

But if there is anyone who can answer my other questions, it will be a great another help ;)

-how is it that there are blogs that has no image in their posts but if you post their posts on facebook, there is a mysterious large thumbnail?

look at this site: the image in the post IS SO SMALL!!!! But when you post its link on Facebook, the thumbnail is large!
http://getrealphilippines.com/blog/2015/03/all-out-war-philippines-kill-em-all-and-let-god-sort-them-out/

Answer (score 1):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='URL OF IMAGE' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
```

use this